# How to use test sample weights for prediction in XGBoost regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to create a custom loss function for my XGBRegressor model where the observations `y` are deviating more from the norm and put more weight on their contribution in the loss function of the model.

```
def custom_loss(wt=wt):
    def custom_se(y_pred, y_true, wt=wt):
        wt_new = abs(16.75 - y_true) * wt
        grad = (y_true - y_pred) * wt_new
        hess = wt_new
        return grad, hess
    return custom_se

xgbr = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective=custom_loss(wt=1))
xgbr.fit(x_train, y_train)

ypred = xgbr.predict(x_test)
```

All the samples will have different weights. How do I use the test sample weights in prediction?

Comment: You don't, and you don't need to; any weighting scheme (be it about classes or individual samples) is meaningful only for training, and meaningless in inference. But this is not a *programming* question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info